# PM2 - problem with the initialization of variables

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, devops, environment, pm2

Is it possible to initialize the environment variables and start the process after the defined time ? Because, at the first start, the process choose the environment by default

I tried to define the specifics env and to use pm2 reload, but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

#### Scheduling in PM2

The scheduling part in PM2 is simply passing the `--cron` (or `-c`) parameter to the `pm2 start` command with the intended cron syntax. You can use [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/) to build the syntax if you're unfamiliar with cron.

#### PM2 Environment

PM2 has a section in it's documentation about how to use `--env` with the `pm2 start` command

#### [Environment Variables](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/environment/):

> PM2 will inject environment in this order when starting a new process :
>
> - First the PM2 CLI will use its environment so the current environment of your shell will be injected.
> - PM2 will then inject the environment that you can configure with the ecosystem file

If you configure your ecosystem file (defualt: `ecosystem.config.js`) with the separate environments (prepend `env_` to the environment names) you can pass these along with the `--env` parameter to the `pm2 start` command. From the documentation:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [
      {
        name: "myapp",
        script: "./app.js",
        watch: true,
        env: {
            "PORT": 3000,
            "NODE_ENV": "development"
        },
        env_production: {
            "PORT": 80,
            "NODE_ENV": "production",
        }
      }
  ]
}
```

You can run `pm2 start --env production`

So running `pm2 start --env NAME --cron "0 1 * * *"` (or whatever cron config you want) should do these things for you